# Quicktime failing to join (or save joined) video clips

Tags: video, quicktime

I have a pair of video clips (mp4) that I would like to join into 1.  The [internet tells me](https://www.cultofmac.com/135696/edit-and-combine-movies-in-quicktime-player-os-x-tips/) that I can do this with Quicktime.

Unfortunately, whenever I try exporting joined clips, with clips of any size, I get the same error:

[image]

"The operation could not be completed; an unknown error occured"

If I try to save, rather than export, I cannot. But if I try and close, I'm given an option to save. If I choose to save then, I get this error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

For full information: there is a two minute video of me running into the problem [here](https://youtu.be/OYKW0RErcxM)

Comment: Same, Problem remain for years, never get fixed and response.

Comment: Same here. Apple is crazy for not fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the video is compressed using an incompatible codec,  why apple has ignored this for 3 years is beyond me.  I used VLC